# How to make a table, but leave out the diagonal elements?

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm making a table called `ac` as shown below. I know that every diagonal expression `as[[1,1]]`, `ac[[2,2]]`, `ac[[3,3]]` etc... will be a divided by 0 expression and I either don't care or don't want to have these elements in my table. The rest of the table is perfectly fine and at the right position. I'm going to calculate the sum of each row at the next step, but that just works, if I can create the table in first place.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
In[108]:= ac = 
Table[G *(mass[[i]]*distance[[k, i]])/Norm[distance[[k, i]]]^3, {k, 
1, 8}, {i, 1, 8}]

During evaluation of In[108]:= Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 
encountered.

During evaluation of In[108]:= Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. 
ComplexInfinity encountered.

During evaluation of In[108]:= Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. 
ComplexInfinity encountered.

During evaluation of In[108]:= Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. 
ComplexInfinity encountered.

During evaluation of In[108]:= General::stop: Further output of 
Infinity::indet will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[108]:= Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. 
encountered.

During evaluation of In[108]:= Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. 
encountered.

During evaluation of In[108]:= General::stop: Further output of Power::infy 
will be suppressed during this calculation.

Out[108]= {{{Indeterminate, Indeterminate, 
Indeterminate}, {-((7.84201*10^-20 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 
0., -((1.4117*10^-18 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3)}, {-((3.97595*10^-16 AU EM)/
Abs[AU]^3), 0., 0.}, {-((6.20493*10^-17 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., 
0.}, {-((5.27797*10^-17 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., 
0.}, {-((3.3151*10^-17 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., 
0.}, {-((4.41643*10^-17 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., 
0.}, {-((7.73514*10^-18 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., 0.}}, {{(
1.46769*10^10 AU)/Abs[AU]^3, 0., (2.64211*10^11 AU)/
Abs[AU]^3}, {Indeterminate, Indeterminate, 
Indeterminate}, {-((4.72876*10^-20 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., (
2.3011*10^-18 AU EM)/
Abs[AU]^3}, {-((3.37047*10^-20 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., (
6.81592*10^-19 AU EM)/
Abs[AU]^3}, {-((8.64357*10^-20 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., (
1.02351*10^-18 AU EM)/
Abs[AU]^3}, {-((1.43257*10^-19 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., (
1.10666*10^-18 AU EM)/
Abs[AU]^3}, {-((3.63108*10^-19 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., (
2.14286*10^-18 AU EM)/
Abs[AU]^3}, {-((1.80594*10^-19 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., (
6.96067*10^-19 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3}}, {{(4.58341*10^13 AU)/Abs[AU]^3, 
0., 0.}, {(2.91264*10^-20 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3, 
0., -((1.41734*10^-18 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3)}, {Indeterminate, 
Indeterminate, 
Indeterminate}, {-((8.19067*10^-16 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., 
0.}, {-((2.5335*10^-16 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., 
0.}, {-((9.56719*10^-17 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., 
0.}, {-((1.00843*10^-16 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., 
0.}, {-((1.3448*10^-17 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., 0.}}, {{(
2.40757*10^13 AU)/Abs[AU]^3, 0., 0.}, {(6.98756*10^-20 AU EM)/
Abs[AU]^3, 0., -((1.41306*10^-18 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3)}, {(
2.75686*10^-15 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3, 0., 0.}, {Indeterminate, 
Indeterminate, 
Indeterminate}, {-((8.44475*10^-16 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., 
0.}, {-((1.7728*10^-16 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., 
0.}, {-((1.55265*10^-16 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., 
0.}, {-((1.74041*10^-17 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., 0.}}, {{(
1.35426*10^13 AU)/Abs[AU]^3, 0., 0.}, {(1.18501*10^-19 AU EM)/
Abs[AU]^3, 0., -((1.4032*10^-18 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3)}, {(
5.63909*10^-16 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3, 0., 0.}, {(5.58443*10^-16 AU EM)/
Abs[AU]^3, 0., 0.}, {Indeterminate, Indeterminate, 
Indeterminate}, {-((5.60293*10^-16 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., 
0.}, {-((3.09456*10^-16 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., 
0.}, {-((2.50619*10^-17 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., 0.}}, {{(
7.75558*10^12 AU)/Abs[AU]^3, 0., 0.}, {(1.79071*10^-19 AU EM)/
Abs[AU]^3, 0., -((1.38333*10^-18 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3)}, {(
1.94158*10^-16 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3, 0., 0.}, {(1.0689*10^-16 AU EM)/
Abs[AU]^3, 0., 0.}, {(5.10856*10^-16 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3, 0., 
0.}, {Indeterminate, Indeterminate, 
Indeterminate}, {-((1.39739*10^-15 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., 
0.}, {-((4.54153*10^-17 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., 0.}}, {{(
5.24316*10^12 AU)/Abs[AU]^3, 0., 0.}, {(2.3033*10^-19 AU EM)/
Abs[AU]^3, 0., -((1.35928*10^-18 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3)}, {(
1.03853*10^-16 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3, 0., 0.}, {(4.75065*10^-17 AU EM)/
Abs[AU]^3, 0., 0.}, {(1.43181*10^-16 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3, 0., 0.}, {(
7.09121*10^-16 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3, 0., 0.}, {Indeterminate, 
Indeterminate, 
Indeterminate}, {-((9.47555*10^-17 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., 0.}}, {{(
2.67508*10^12 AU)/Abs[AU]^3, 0., 0.}, {(3.33707*10^-19 AU EM)/
Abs[AU]^3, 0., -((1.28621*10^-18 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3)}, {(
4.03439*10^-17 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3, 0., 0.}, {(1.55123*10^-17 AU EM)/
Abs[AU]^3, 0., 0.}, {(3.3779*10^-17 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3, 0., 0.}, {(
6.71357*10^-17 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3, 0., 0.}, {(2.76027*10^-16 AU EM)/
Abs[AU]^3, 0., 0.}, {Indeterminate, Indeterminate, Indeterminate}}}
```

Comment: If you provide the definitions for `distance`, `mass`, and `G`, we may be able to say something useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do

```
Table[If[i == j, "zero", i j], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}]
MatrixForm @ %
```

[image]

---

Or

```
Table[i j (1 - KroneckerDelta[i, j]), {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}]
MatrixForm @ %
```

[image]

but I guess that if your function (which I took simply as `i*j`) is singular at `i==j`, this will still yield an error about a `1/0` expression. So an `If` is the way to go.

Comment: I tried like this:

ac = Table[
  if[i == k, 
   "zero", {G *(mass[[i]]*distance[[k, i]])/
      Norm[distance[[k, i]]]^3}], {k, 1, 8}, {i, 1, 8}]

But then it makes it like this, and still the same error messages:


{{if[True, "zero", {{Indeterminate, Indeterminate, Indeterminate}}], 
  if[False, 
   "zero", {{-((7.84201*10^-20 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 
     0., -((1.4117*10^-18 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3)}}], 
  if[False, "zero", {{-((3.97595*10^-16 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., 0.}}], 
  if[False, "zero", {{-((6.20493*10^-17 AU EM)/Abs[AU]^3), 0., 0.}}],

Comment: Change `if` to `If`.

Comment: Works pertfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of thing, I like to define a function. For example:

```
f[i_, j_] := i j;
f[i_, i_] := 0;
Table[f[i, j], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}]
```

gives the same matrix as @corey979's. You would, of course, replace the first definition of f[i,j] with your own function.

Answer (score 0):

You could block [`DirectedInfinity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirectedInfinity) so that it is 0. For example:

```
SeedRandom[1];
Block[{DirectedInfinity = 0&},
    Quiet @ Table[i (j/RandomInteger[]), {i,3}, {j,3}]
]
```

> {{1, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {0, 6, 0}}